# Haproxy: Keepalive connections not balanced evenly

Tags: haproxy, keep-alive

we’ve got a strange little problem we’re experiencing for months now:

The load on our cluster (http, long lasting keepalive connections with a lot of very short (<100ms) requests) is distributed very uneven.
All servers are configured the same way but some connections that push through thousands of requests per second just end up being sent to only one server.
We tried both load balancing strategies but that does not help.
It seems to be strictly keepalive related.

The misbehaving backend has the following settings:

```
option tcpka
option http-pretend-keepalive
```

Is the `option http-server-close` made to cover that issue?
If I get it right it will close and re-open a lot of connections which means load to the systems? Isn't there a way to keep the connections open but evenly balance the traffic anyway?
I tried to enable that option but it kills all of our backends when under load.

Answer (score 4):

HAProxy currently only support keep-alive HTTP-connections toward the client, not the server. If you want to be able to inspect (and balance) each HTTP request, you currently *have* to use one of the following options

```
# enable keepalive to the client
option http-server-close

# or

# disable keepalive completely
option httpclose
```

The `option http-pretend-keepalive` doesn't change the actual behavior of HAProxy in regards of connection handling. Instead, it is intended as a workaround for servers which don't work well when they see a non-keepalive connection (as is generated by HAProxy to the backend server).

Support for keep-alive towards the backend server is scheduled to be in the final HAProxy 1.5 release. But the actual scope of that might still vary and the final release date is sometime in the future...

Comment: and it is not included in the current beta?

Comment: Not yet, no. But as I said, Willy has commit himself to that feature.

Comment: Note that since this was written, HAProxy 1.5 was released. It support keepalive-connections all the way from the frontend to the to the backend. It does not however support connection pooling, i.e. sending requests from multiple frontend-connections over a single backend connection. This might be part of 1.6 someday though.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, it's present in the latest release 1.5-dev20 (but take the fixes with it, as it shipped with a few regressions).